# Error: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am just a newbie to MVC and learning through online tutorial. In my code, I am just retrieving data from the database using entity framework. I added `[Key]` attribute in model but still I faced that exception error. What else should i have to do to run the application? Really, need help!

Controller:

```
public class EmployeeDetailsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult details(int id)
    {
        EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee employee = employeecontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.emp_id == id);
        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

Employeecontext.cs

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee.cs:

```
[Table("tbl_employee")]
public class Employee
{
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int emp_id { get; set; }
    public string emp_name { get; set; }
    public string emp_email { get; set; }
}
```

view (details.cs.html):

```
....
<h2> Employee Details</h2>
<div>
    Customer id : @Model.emp_id
    Customer name : @Model.emp_name
    Customer email : @Model.emp_email
</div>
```

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext"
        connectionString="Data Source=192.168.4.201;Initial Catalog=nhphealthnew1;User ID=teamaardee;Password=team@aardee#1234#!" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Debug your code! What line of code throws the exception, and what are the details of the exception.

Comment: `Employee.cs:` was the autogenerated class of EF?

Comment: after debug the code got error in the Employeedetailscontroller ,   " Employee employee = employeecontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.emp_id == id); "                                                                             Error : An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: @ M Adeel Khalid ,  Sir i created  that class where i define the fields.

Comment: Provide inner exception details too. Watch out for EF column names and property constraints, they need to be on-sync with database properties.

Comment: create table tbl_employee
(
 id int identity not null primary key,
 name varchar(20),
 email varchar(20),
 phone varchar(20)
)                                                  DATABASE TABLE

Comment: @ Tetsuya Yamamoto... I already mentioned the inner exception and code  , where i am actually getting error above....please do have a look..!!!

Comment: You have NOT told us the error details (the message your getting even tells you **See the inner exception for details.** - what is it? (we are not psychic). Add it to your question!

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke.. while i am click on the inner exception details; it will redirect me to the microsoft documentation link. So, how could i mentioned you...!!!

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
try{
    EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext ();
    Employee employee = employeecontext.Employees.Where( e=> e.ID == id ).First();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline ("Exception: " + ex.toString());
}
```

And Post the output here please.
Oh and don't forget to check if you have a table called "tbl_employee" with correct columns in your "nhphealthnew1" database

Comment: @ Elvin No Matter                                                                                    ok  i will try this ..!!!

Answer (score 0):

iam following the same tutorial and ia also faced this problem and i find the solution by adding this cod at **web.config** by this way

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="EmployeeContext"  
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  
        connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Sample;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

[image]